# Laravel Push Item into hasManyRelation Builder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In laravel model I have a relation

```
public function photos()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Photo::class, 'item_id');
}
```

It returns associated image with the item. Now I thought to add one addition image in all products of specific category and brand. So logically I am getting item and if it falls into required section, I want to push an image. I modified my code to look like this.

```
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany|Builder
     */
    public function photos()
    {
        if($this->category_id = 10 && $this->brand_id ==1){
            /**
             * Add an additional image in specific type of products, here apple phones
             */
            $photos = Photo::where('item_id', $this->id)->get();
            $additionalPhoto = new Photo();
            $additionalPhoto->item_id = $this->id;
            $additionalPhoto->image_name = 'https://si.wsj.net/public/resources/images/RV-AK835_INNOVA_P_20130614181900.jpg';
            $additionalPhoto->image_resized = false;
            $photos->push($additionalPhoto);
           return $photos;
        }else{
            return $this->hasMany(Photo::class, 'item_id');
        }
    }
```

When I do `dd($photos)` after pushing the photo it gives as expected results. But the only thing is it would work with collection and not relation.  This relation has been used at multiple place so I don't want to change it to return collection.

**Is is possible with relation to push data like this**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a relationship method should be altered with this kind of logic as it would break the relationship in one or another way.

To push using an existing relationship you can use something like this in your controller:

```
//Retrieve products
Product::where('category_id', 10)
    ->whereHas('brand', function ($q) {
        $q->where('id', 1);
    })
    //Your relationship. item_id is not needed, since the relationship is defined with it
    ->photos()->create([
        'image_name' => 'https://si.wsj.net/public/resources/images/RV-AK835_INNOVA_P_20130614181900.jpg',
        'image_resized' => false
    ]);
```

I haven’t tested this, but using it in a similar way however, you can keep your relationship and directly add data using it.